# Naming of bool paramaters in command

Tags: naming

Booleans are being prefixed with the can, shall, will, is etc 
in order to indicate its type (boolean) and I guess even more important:
it's meaning.

But when it comes to commands (void methods) I find it not as simple.
I saw commands like enable(bool) parameter which sets a value true or false.

But I don't think that a method called enable(...) should ever do a "disable".

I'd prefer making an addition method which disables() without parameter or a method called Set...(bool param)

But which convention describes how this parameter should be called?
The approach prefixing it with Is is a bit confusing in my opinion as Is
always indicates a state of something but not but if want to set a boolean value via a command explicitly I don't think it makes sense to prefix the parameter.

How would you name such a function(s parameter)?

```
void SetHasSpecialSetting(bool flag) => this.HasSpecialSetting=flag;
```

Update:
As I pointed out, prefixing booleans imply that their type is bool obviously.
More over it makes it more readable in situation where you need this bool as condition. 
But for commands that only set a bool property to a given value it is not needed to know the meaning of the property nor that it is of type bool because that i clear.

Comment: Rule #1 be consistent with the rest of the codebase.

Comment: IMO, I prefer `SetHasSpecialSettting` for Java/C++, since it's not clear at first if `HasSpecialSetting` is a setter or a getter. For C# where I can make it both, I prefer `HasSpecialSetting`.

Comment: I agree with your point regarding consistency. I still think that it would be better to name bool parameter in commands without prefixes or whatsoever. see update.

Comment: Hi; this kind of question is off-topic as it is about word choice rather than about programming as defined by the [help].

Answer (score 0):

First, I agree with the commenters: if there is a naming rule in the project, use it.

While your implementation is also good, I do not prefer that approach, using  generic function + parameter(s). When I have to implement something similar, I prefer (in pseudocode):

```
set ( parameter ) => parameter = true
reset ( parameter ) => parameter = false
```

or:

```
setParameter () => parameter = true
resetParameter () => parameter = false
```

For me, this is easier to read. I moved the true / false information into the name of the function. Other people use `clear` instead of `reset`. That is also very good, but again, that is not my preference.

**Bottom line:**

**Firstly**, study the project (or talk to the people) and find the currently used naming rules. Follow them if they exist.

**Secondly**, make your decision based on the facts.